# How to vertically align images without absolute positioning in a responsive layout

Tags: html, css, image, position

I know that `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` make an element to be centered as `text-align:center;` does.

My question is about the vertical alignment.

I would like to keep my images centered in relation with my vh.

```
<section> 
  <div class="half">
    <img />
  </div>

  <div class="half">
    <img />
  </div>
</section>
```

STYLE:

```
.half {
height:100%;
width: 50%;
display:inline-block;
float:left;  
}

.half img {
max-width:93%;
max-height:90%;
}
```

An example on Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/f16wpgpm/3/

Comment: I need to say that the `display:table` and `display:table-cell` method is not what I'm looking for, because I need my images to be automatically resized with my vh and vw. Look at my example: the images are NEVER cutted out of the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position:relative;` to `.half` and then add the following CSS to your `img` selector:

```
margin: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f16wpgpm/5/)

Comment: Nice. What if I need to keep my images close to each other like in the example, instead of have them horizontally centered?
http://jsfiddle.net/f16wpgpm/3/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/f16wpgpm/6/

you can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` for this.

```
section {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

.half {
    width: 50%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the table display method to vertically align responsively. However, this requires an inner `<div>` to act as the cell to align:

```
<div class="half first_half">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="http://www.capitale-creativo.it/img/capcrea1.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then by making `.half` display as a table and the `.inner` display as its cell, you can add a `vertical-align: middle;` like so:

```
.half{
    height:100%;
    width: 50%;
    display:table;
    float:left;
}

.inner{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/f16wpgpm/4/